# Firebase what state is a batched write in after a commit?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

### Question

After committing a batch using `batch.commit()` are the executed `batch.set()` operations cleared off the variable?

### Explanation

Say i have a list of 1000 (or so) items that i need to write to Firestore.

I can cycle through them and on every 500th cycle i'll just commit the batch.

Now this the loop continues (after the first 500 elements for example) to add the 501st, 502nd ... up to 1000th element using `batch.set()`

Reaching 1000, the code needs to execute `batch.commit()` the second time, but if the batch variable was not reset after the first commit, 1000 elements will be in the batch leading to a crash

### Example Code

```
function batchWrite () {
    const batch = writeBatch(db)
    somearray.foreach((element: any, index :Number) => {
        const someRef = doc(db, 'blablabla')
        batch.set(someRef, element)

        const indexDivBy500 = index / 500
        //True if index is divisible by 500 without remainder
        const commitBatch = (indexDivBy500 - Math.floor(indexDivBy500)) == 0; 
    
        if(commitBatch) {
            batch.commit()

            //something along the lines of batch.clear()?
            //because after the commit, the foreach may continue with index 501...
        }

    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `createBatch` to create a new batch after committing the previous. In code:

```
if (commitBatch) {
    batch.commit()
    batch = writeBatch(db) // 
}
```